# How do I detect when i release mouse button in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I detect when I release the left mouse button in a VB program?

So currently using:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
   PictureBox1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Means whenever I click my button the picturebox appears.
So how do I get the picturebox to disappear when I release the mouse button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event will only occur after the the user releases the mouse button.  A click occurs when the left mouse button is pressed and released.

You want to use the [MouseDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) and [MouseUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx) events.

Comment: @user1868155: if it answers your question, please consider accepting.